# Page permalink ending in "-2"

Tags: permalinks, pages, child-pages

I have a couple of child pages that keeping ending in "-2" on the permalink even if I go in and manually change the permalink. I do not have any pages that are a duplicate title of these so I have no clue why the "-2" keeps popping up on the permalink. Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you have *do* have duplicates - duplicate permalinks, not necessarily duplicate titles per se. Have you trashed some posts with duplicate permalinks? Until you empty the WP trash, WP still considers their slugs in use. Also, what about Custom Post Types?